# Converting to Swift 3 renamed my own Objective-C method

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3

I have swift classes mixed in with my Objective-C code. With Swift 2.3, everything was fine and worked as expected.

I recently converted to Swift 3, and it updates several API calls because of all the renaming that occurred for Swift 3. That's fine; I get that.

But what's not fine is that Swift 3 seems to have renamed a method in one of *my* Objective-C classes. I own the Objective-C class and I called the method what I wanted: `readDeliveryInfoItems`. But now, after converting to Swift 3, I can't call `.readDeliveryInfoItems()` anymore in my Swift class. It's telling me it has been renamed to `.readItems()`.

That makes no sense. And the Objective-C class still calls the method `readDeliveryInfoItems`, so there is something under the covers going on here.

I have tried renaming the Objective-C `readDeliveryInfoItems` method to `readDeliveryInfo`, building (Swift fails because it says that the `readInfo()` method doesn't exist, which is good), and then renaming the method back to `readDeliveryInfoItems`. However, when I build after this, Swift goes back to thinking the method is called `readInfo()`. I was hoping this would trick Xcode into refreshing the Swift bridging and renaming the method back to the correct name `readDeliveryInfoItems()`, but it did not.

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE TO ADD MORE INFO**

The interface of my Objective-C class has this function declaration:

```
- (nullable NSArray<XMPPDeliveryInfoItem *> *)readDeliveryInfoItems;
```

But in the Generated Interface (see MartinR's comment below) for that class, the function declaration is this instead:

```
open func readItems() -> [XMPPDeliveryInfoItem]?
```

There are other functions in that class that are similar to the `readDeliveryInfoItems` function, such as this one:

```
- (nullable NSArray<XMPPDeliveryInfoItem *> *)sentDeliveryInfoItems;
```

And they look correct in the Generated Interface:

```
open func sentDeliveryInfoItems() -> [XMPPDeliveryInfoItem]?
```

So I can't figure out why I'm having this problem with only the one function.

Comment: You can use `NS_SWIFT_NAME` to control the Swift name mapping, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39203235/use-objective-c-method-in-swift-seems-crossing-keyword-of-swift-language for an example.

Comment: The Swift 3 compiler does **not** change anything in your Objective-C files, it adapts only the Swift 3 naming convention on the Swift side.

Comment: @MartinR thanks...yeah that works...but I really don't want to have to do that in this case for this one method, and I definitely don't think I should have to.

Comment: In any case, it would be helpful to see a (minimal) self-contained example of the ObjC interface and the Swift mapping.

Comment: @MartinR when you say "Swift mapping", what do you mean? How can I view that? I know how to view the bridging header and the -Swift.h file, but none of those show how the Objective-C code is being compiled to work in Swift. The bridging header shows what you want to be able to use in Swift, and the -Swift.h file shows what you can use from Swift in your Objective-C. Is there something else to look at in regards to the "Swift mapping"?

Comment: You can view the "Generated Interface" of C/Objective-C headers, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1914/_index.html for instructions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The translation process is described in detail in

- [SE-0005 Better Translation of Objective-C APIs Into Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md)

The relevant part for your question is (emphasis mine):

> **Prune a match for the enclosing type** from the base name of a method so
>   long as the match starts **after a verb.** For example,
>
> ```
> extension UIViewController {
>   func dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)
> }
> ```
>
> becomes:
>
> ```
> extension UIViewController {
>   func dismissAnimated(flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)
> }
> ```

This pruning algorithm is – as far as I can see – implemented in 
[StringExtras.cpp](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/Basic/StringExtras.cpp) (and uses a lot of heuristics),
and [PartsOfSpeech.def](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/Basic/PartsOfSpeech.def)
contains a list of words which are considered a **verb,** such as

```
VERB(dismiss)
VERB(read)
VERB(send)
```

but *not* `VERB(sent)`. That explains why – simplifying your example slightly –

```
@interface DeliveryInfo : NSObject
-(void)readDeliveryInfoItems;
-(void)sentDeliveryInfoItems;
@end
```

becomes

```
open class DeliveryInfo : NSObject {
    open func readItems()
    open func sentDeliveryInfoItems()
}
```

The type name is pruned after the verb "read", but not after the
non-verb "sent". (You can verify that by changing the second method
name to `sendDeliveryInfoItems` which is then mapped to `sendItems()`.)

You can override the mapping with `NS_SWIFT_NAME`:

```
-(void)readDeliveryInfoItems NS_SWIFT_NAME(readDeliveryInfoItems());
```

Comment: And the compiler can't tell that you mean "read" (the past participle of the verb *to read*) and not the active verb. Silly English for making those tenses the same for that word... ;) +1 for `NS_SWIFT_NAME` if you want to keep either the longer construction for "read" or the shorter construction for "sent".

Comment: @rickster: Apparently the compiler does not *listen* carefully, isn't "read" pronounced differently from "read"?

Comment: Good point. You should file a bug on that... I bet Apple's accessibility folks would want to get right on it. Till then, I suppose the workaround is to use IPA for all identifiers.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks very much for this...very informative.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking (and I am oversimplifying), if the suffix on a method name is a verb object matching the return type, the suffix is dropped.

A simpler example would be a method called `readString` that returns an NSString.

Your method falls within those parameters (I told you I was oversimplifying but you can see, roughly, how that's true), so you get the treatment.

Personally, I regard this as a bug, especially because in some cases the change can result in name clash and make calling the method *impossible* (esp. when the Objective-C API is not yours and you cannot change it). For an example, see this question: [Swift 3 (Omit Needless Words) causing two functions to have the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835592/swift-3-omit-needless-words-causing-two-functions-to-have-the-same-name)