# Getting wrong property for a Objective-C class from Swift 3.0

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3

I had a piece of code that was working on Swift 2.X version, but, after update the code and syntax to Swift 3.0 it is working on a strange way.

I have the following structure wrote on Objective-C:

Class A:

```
@interface A : NSObject
{
    // some properties
}
```

Class Expense:

```
@interface Expense : A {
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* Description;
}
```

On Swift 2.X I had the following code:

```
if let expense = DataManager.sharedDataManager().expenseForExpenseId(id) {
    var description = expense.Description
}
```

When I updated to Swift 3.0 the code was changed to:

```
if let expense = DataManager.shared().expense(forExpenseId: id) {
   // expense is a variable from the Expense class
   var description = expense.description
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that when I use `expense.description` I'm getting the value for the description (*lowerCamelCase*) property from the **NSObject class** (parent of parent class) instead of the value for the Description (*UpperCamelCase*) property from the **Expense Class**. I had to change the expenseType.Description to expenseType.description because of the new syntax on Swift 3.0

I have a workaround to fix it, create a get method on the Expense Class and call it from Swift 3.0:

```
@interface Expense : A {
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* Description;
    -(NSString*) getDescription(){
        return Description;
    }
}
```

Is this a known problem? Do you know a better solution for this problem?

Comment: I would just rename the property, `Description` is a bad choice,  it does not follow any naming conventions and could conflict with `description` in other situations like Key-Value Coding. If that is not possible, define a different name for Swift with NS_SWIFT_NAME, see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157131/converting-to-swift-3-renamed-my-own-objective-c-method for an example.

Comment: ya you should change the property name. Do not use `description`