# Bumping from ReactiveCocoa 2.4.7 to ReactiveCocoa 5.0.0

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-5

I have taken over an iOS-project which implements `ReactiveCocoa 2.4.7` using CocoaPods. The app was programmed in Swift 1.2, but has later been upgraded, and is now Swift 2.3. However, ReactiveCocoa has not been updated.
I am now in a situation where my goal is to upgrade the app to Swift 3, but to do this, I will have to upgrade ReactiveCocoa as well.

In ReactiveCocoa 2.4.7, if I am correct, I am able to observe values that inherit from NSObject, as long as they have the `dynamic` keyword. From what I understand, this is to make it accessible to RAC which is made in Objective-C. Is there no such thing in 5.0.0? Do I have to change all my variables from

`dynamic var name:String? = "MyName"`

to

`let name:MutableProperty<String?> = MutableProperty("MyName")` ?

Is this the correct equivalent in 5.0.0?

Comment: Yes. If you don't use the Cocoa part, you can just install `ReactiveSwift` anyway,

Answer (score 0):

ReactiveCocoa 2.4.7 is written in ObjC. If can upgrade the project to Swift 3 **without** upgrading ReactiveCocoa.

All the changes you'll have to make for ReactiveCocoa 2.4.7 to work in Swift 3 will be due to the change in how [Swift 3 imports ObjC Code compared to how Swift 2 did](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md).

See this related question. [Converting to Swift 3 renamed my own Objective-C method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157131/converting-to-swift-3-renamed-my-own-objective-c-method)

Regarding your equivalence question, the answer is Yes and No.

**No:** In RAC 2.x you could observe any property of a `NSObject` via the `RACObserve` macro which works via KVO (in Swift you had to use a [wrapper](https://github.com/ashfurrow/Swift-RAC-Macros) for the macro). For this to work with in Swift, you'll need to use the `dynamic` keyword for the property to enable KVO.

The equivalent to this in RAC 5.0 is `DynamicProperty<Value>`.
However, as the documentation states:

> Use this class only as a last resort! `MutableProperty` is generally better unless KVC/KVO is required by the API you're using

Therefore:

**Yes:**, `MutableProperty` most of the time is the correct equivalent. But it requires you to make more changes and will not work the same way as `RACObserve` did.

With `RACObserve` or `DynamicProperty`, you would just set `person.name = "Rudolph"`, and Observers of the `name` property would be called.

With `MutableProperty`, you will have to set `person.name.value = "Rudolph"`.