# Xcode thinks method name has been changed

Tags: swift, xcode, methods

I get an error when I try to debug my app on xcode. It thinks the name of the method has been changed. The method is created in a Objective C class and I call it in a Swift class. It worked before I changed to Swift 3.

```
+(NSString *)retriveDataFromPlist:(NSString *)file key:(NSString *)key;
```

Here is the line where I call the method

```
UniversalMethods.retriveDataFromPlist("settings.plist", key:"name")
```

Here is what xcode suggests.

```
UniversalMethods.retriveData(fromPlist: "settings.plist", key:"name")
```

Comment: I suggest it is because with swift 3 the objective-c bridged function names are automatically formed to the new syntax. If it doesn't compile, try to update your Obj-c method name as it requeires

Comment: The Swift 3 importer *does* rename methods, compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157131/converting-to-swift-3-renamed-my-own-objective-c-method for a similar issue.

Comment: was retrieve misspelled in the original? Maybe it should be: "retrieveDataFromPlist"

Comment: Swift 3 changed to encourage us to name the first variable passed into a function. So all default methods now require it