# Calling Objective-C function from Swift with parameter

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm working with third-party project, which I need to modify. Currently I've met the following strange code:

A function is declared as follows in Obj-C:

```
@interface CVASPlayer : NSObject

+ (void)optimizeForTheory:(CVGame *)game;

@end

@implementation CVASPlayer

+ (void)optimizeForTheory:(CVGame *)game {
    ASGamerParser::optimizeForTheory((Game *)[game getCPPClass]);
}

@end
```

And it is called from Swift as:

```
CVASPlayer.optimize(forTheory: game)
```

The method names doesn't match - `optimize` and `optimizeForTheory`. How it works? And `forTheory` is strangely moved to a parameter name, how is it possible?

Comment: The naming convention is different in Obj-C and Swift and hence the generated Swift headers for Obj-C functions will have different naming than in Obj-C. You can check the generated Swift header file in Xcode by opening the header file for the Obj-C implementation file, then clicking on the `Related Items` button and selecting `Counterparts` --> Swift header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting to Swift 3 renamed my own Objective-C method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157131/converting-to-swift-3-renamed-my-own-objective-c-method)