# why Objective-C convert to swift wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

why

```
 -(void)addSimpleListener:(id<XXSimpleListener>)listener
```

convert to swift look like this:

```swift
func add(_ listener: XXSimpleListener?) {   
}
```

but change the method to this

```
 -(void)addSimpleListener:(id<XXSimpleListening>)listener
```

and it will convert to this

```
func addSimpleListener(_ listener: XXSimpleListening?){
}
```

Comment: You mean "why Xcode will automatically rename the method to `add` in the first case?"

Comment: Possibly helpful (if not duplicate): [Converting to Swift 3 renamed my own Objective-C method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157131/converting-to-swift-3-renamed-my-own-objective-c-method).

Answer (score 0):

Xcode (or whatever tool you are using to do the conversion) is merely following [Swift API guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#promote-clear-usage). Specifically:

> Omit needless words. Every word in a name should convey salient information at the use site.
>
> More words may be needed to clarify intent or disambiguate meaning, but those that are redundant with information the reader already possesses should be omitted. In particular, omit words that *merely repeat* type information.

In the first case, the words `SimpleListener` in `addSimpleListener` is repeating the type of the parameter, so they are removed from the method name. However, in the second case, `SimpleListener` and `SimpleListening` does not look the same to whatever tool you are using, so it thinks that `SimpleListener` should be kept.

In my (human) opinion though, I think the method should be named `addListener`, because:

> Occasionally, repeating type information is necessary to avoid ambiguity, but in general it is better to use a word that describes a parameter’s *role* rather than its type.

`Listener` is the role of the parameter.